# Terminal emulator that allows dynamically change of background color

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm currently trying to find a terminal emulator, for a Linux-based system, that allows me to change the background depending on what application I'm running.

I'm thinking that this should be pretty easy to do with some [OSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences) escape-sequence, but I can't find any documentation about there being any terminal supporting it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

If your terminal emulator supports Background Color Erase (BCE), you could use an "erase display" escape sequence to set the display's background color. For example, this sets the background to red in Bash:

```
tput setab 1; tput clear
```

`tput setab 1` sets the "ANSI Background Color" to 1 (Red). `put clear` clears the screen, usually by emitting the codes to move the cursor to the top/left corner and clear the display. If you don't want to erase the entire display, you can just erase from the current line to the end of the display:

```
tput setab 1; tput ed
```

If your terminal emulator supports BCE, various commands that clear portions of the display will fill the cleared area with the current background color. You can tell if your terminal emulator supports BCE using `tput`:

```
tput bce && echo Yes || echo No
```

This will display "Yes" if BCE is supported.

To make use of this, you can use shell functions (or script files) to wrap the commands you want to set the color for. E.g., in Bash, this will set the display to blue when running *ssh*:

```
ssh () {
    trap 'tput sgr0; tput ed' RETURN;
    tput setab 4; tput ed
    command ssh $*;
}
```

Using `trap` ensures it resets the background color (and other text attributes) when the function returns. I've used `tput ed` here, so it only affects the background color of the lines output while running the *ssh* command. You can use `tput clear` if you'd rather fill the entire display and you don't mind erasing the current contents at the start (and/or end) of the command.

Of course, if anything you do with the remote host changes the background color, it will override your color.

Comment: This isn't what I mean. What you are talking about is changing the default background color value for the current terminal session (or current function call when using trap), which is a really nice solution! I applaud this and think I will find use of it. It's not what I had in mind tho... but it could be the very reason why, what I have in mind isn't implemented anywhere. I want to be able to change the background color in the graphical (X-part) of the terminal to be able to use things like transparency effect and in general tint the background towards a certain color.

Comment: I think Xterm will let you programmatically change the terminal color scheme using OSC escape sequences. Is it important that you be able to run the commands inside the same shell session and change the appearance of the terminal, or would it suffice to run the command in a new terminal with the desired appearance? The latter can be accomplished with Terminal in a few different ways that can work automatically. I can post them in another answer if that might help.

Comment: Doing it by OSC esc-seq is what I want to do, I really don't want to start up a new terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with xterm using xtermset:

```
xtermset -bg darkred
```

or xtermcontrol:

```
xtermcontrol --bg=darkred
```

Comment: *xtermset* is not installed by default on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce) terminal for [cmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmus) and change the background based on the cover art. For changing the background, I use `sed`-`sleep`-`sed` to make it realize that the image has changed (I would love to know a better way):

```
sed -i "s:/path/to/old/image:null:g" $HOME/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc ; \
    sleep 1; \
    sed -i "s:null:/path/to/new/image:g" $HOME/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
```